# Inserting std::map through constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, stdmap

So I have a student class with a map for course names and grades and I dont know the syntax for the constructor in main.

```
class Student{

public:

    const string& name;
    const string& personalInfo;
    map<string,int> grade_list;
    Student(const string &name, const string &personalInfo, map<string, int> gradeList)
            : name(name), personalInfo(personalInfo), grade_list(gradeList) {}};
int main(){

    Student s("Arthur","english student",{"French",5});
}
```

Comment: Are you asking about what the `{"engleza",5}` part in main does?

Comment: that part is not correct, im asking how should I insert those correctly, as in the student Arthur, personal information english student, on French course, has grade 5.

Comment: One more pair of braces (one for the map, one for the key/value pair): `Student s("Arthur","english student",{{"French",5}});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax error as you already guessed. Fix it like this:

```
Student s("Arthur", "english student", {{"French",5}} );
```

You need to curly-brace the map *and* its values.